# How do I optimize an ActiveRecord find_in_batches query?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm using Rails 4.0.0 and Ruby 2.0.0.  My `Post` (as in blog posts) model is associated with a user with a combination of the user's user_name, first_name, last_name.  I'd like to migrate the data so that posts are associated to users by a foreign key, which is the user's id.

I have about 11 million records in the `posts` table.

I'm running the below code to migrate the data, using a rake task on a Linux server.  However, my task keeps getting "Killed" by the sever, presumably due to the rake task, specifically the below code, consuming too much memory.

I've found that lowering the `batch_size` to 20 and increasing `sleep(10)` to `sleep(60)` allows the task to run longer, updating more records in total without being Killed, but takes significantly more time.

**How can I optimize this code for speed and memory usage?**

```
Post.where(user_id: nil).find_in_batches(batch_size: 1000) do |posts|
  puts "*** Updating batch beginning with post #{posts.first.id}..."
  sleep(10) # Hopefully, saving some memory usage.
  posts.each do |post|
    begin
      user = User.find_by(user_name: post.user_name, first_name: post.first_name, last_name: post.last_name)
      post.update(user_id: user.id)
    rescue NoMethodError => error # user could be nil, so user.id will raise a NoMethodError
      puts "No user found."
    end
  end
  puts "*** Finished batch."
end
```

Comment: Iff there's a better AR way than `find_in_batches`, that would be a welcome answer!

Comment: You could do this with a single `UPDATE` statement instead of having to go through the model layer. Also using `sleep` has zero effect on memory usage, it just slows it down. If you're really up against the wall on memory usage, call `GC.start` after each iteration. Pretty sure you could do all of this in a simple migration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do all the work in the database which is WAY faster than moving data back and forth.

This can be accomplished with ActiveRecord.
Of course PLEASE test this before you unleash it on important data.

```
Post
  .where(user_id: nil)
  .joins("inner join users on posts.user_name = users.user_name")
  .update_all("posts.user_id = users.id")
```

Further, if posts have an index on `user_id`, and users has an index on `user_name`, then that will help this particular query run more quickly.

Comment: This reduced the time to run the script on the data by about half! Thanks so much. On it's own, it did not prevent my script from being killed by the server.  I still needed to utilize batch queries.

Comment: Glad it helped. If posts have a user_id index, and users has a user_name index, that will make this particular query faster. Not sure what you have.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the `#uncached` method on AR models. Basically, for request optimization, AR will cache a lot of query data as it is doing `#find_in_batches`, but it's a hinderance to large processing scripts like this.

```
Post.uncached do
  # perform all your heavy query magic here
end
```

Ultimately, if that doesn't work, consider using the `mysql2` gem to avoid the AR overhead, as long as you're not depending on any callbacks/business logic in the update.

Comment: Amazingly, this helped me run my code without being killed by the server! However, it didn't have a noticeable effect in speed.

Answer (score 2):

If a join is possible I'd go with the approach from [z5h](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36650450/2786269).
Otherwise you could add an index to the user model (possibly in a separate migration) and also skip the validations, callbacks and stuff when updating each post:

```
add_index :users, [:user_name, :first_name, :last_name] # Speed up search queries
Post.where(user_id: nil).find_each do |post|
  if user = User.find_by(user_name:  post.user_name,
                         first_name: post.first_name,
                         last_name:  post.last_name)
    post.update_columns(user_id: user.id) # ...to skip validations and callbacks.
  end
end
```

Please note that `find_each` is equivalent to `find_in_batches` + iterating over each post, but possibly not faster (see Rails Guides on [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects-in-batches))

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks.  Seems like not a bad idea, but I'm trying to move my database away from looking up the user by that three-column combo, so I was thinking it best not to index if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

Combining other answers, I was able to join tables, and update multiple columns, in batches of 1000 rows, with a reduction in speed and without my process being killed by the server.

Here's the combines approach that I found to work best, keeping the code within the ActiveRecord API as much as possible.

```
Post.uncached do
  Post.where(user_id: nil, organization_id: nil).find_each do |posts|
    puts "** Updating batch beginning with post #{posts.first.id}..."

    # Update 1000 records at once
    posts.map!(&:id) # posts is an array, not a relation
    Post.where(id: posts).
      joins("INNER JOIN users ON (posts.user_name = users.user_name)").
      joins("INNER JOIN organizations ON (organizations.id = users.organization_id)").
      update_all("posts.user_id = users.id, posts.organization_id = organizations.id")

    puts "** Finished batch."
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add new temporary boolean attribute updated

```
Post.where(updated: false).find_in_batches(batch_size: 1000) do |posts|
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    puts "*** Updating batch beginning with post #{posts.first.id}..."
    posts.each do |post|
      user = User.find_by(user_name: post.user_name, first_name: post.first_name, last_name: post.last_name)
      if user
        post.update_columns(user_id: user.id, updated: true)
      else
        post.update_columns(updated: true)
      end
    end
    puts "*** Finished batch."
  end
end
```